# Deleting vertex with a degree of millions scale from JanusGraph

Tags: database, graph, janusgraph

- I am running Janusgraph with Scylla as a storage engine.
- The graph has a vertex with a degree of 5M (in + out), i.e. around 5M vertices are connected to it,
- I am trying to drop this vertex by gremlin query `graph.traversal().V(vertexId).drop().iterate()` but it's taking a lot of time (unable to delete in 20 minutes).
- I understand that above query iterates all edges and does the actual deletion

I wanted to know if anyone has faced a similar issue and figured out any workaround on it. Any lead would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

My information may be dated and perhaps there are revised ways to do this, but since there have been no responses on this question I figured I'd offer the advice as I know it. In the days before JanusGraph when this graph was called Titan and I had situations like the one you describe, I found similar results that you are finding when doing a direct `g.V(id).drop()` and that to fully get rid of the vertex of that size meant having some patience. The strategy I used to get rid of it involved pruning the vertex of its edges so that a delete of the vertex itself became possible.

How you go about pruning the edges is dependent on your data and how those 5M edges are composed. It could be as simple as doing it by label or by blocks of 10000 within each label at a time or something else that makes sense to break the process down into chunks.

```
while(g.V(vertexId).outE('knows').limit(1).hasNext()) {
    g.V(vertexId).outE('knows').limit(10000).drop().iterate();
}
```

I think I recall that I was able to run these types of operates in parallel which sped the process a bit. In any case, when you get the vertex bare of all edges (or down to a significantly smaller degree size at least) you can then `g.V(vertexId).drop()` and say good-bye to it.

I didn't use ScyllaDB but I think I remember that this many deletes can create tombstone types of issues for Cassandra, so that's worth looking out for potentially. You might also look at increasing the various timeouts that might come into play during this process.

For me, the lesson I learned over the years with respect to this issue was to build OLAP based monitors that keep track of graph statistics to ensure that you have proper and expected growth within your graph (i.e. degree distribution, label distributions, etc). This is especially important with graphs being fed from high-volume streams like Kafka where you can turn your head for a few hours and come back and find your graph in an ugly unexpected state. I think it's also important to model in ways that work around the possibility of getting to these supernode states. Edge TTLs and unidirectional edges can help with that in many cases.

I would love to hear that this answer is no longer relevant and that there are neat new ways to do these sorts of drops or that there is some ScyllaDB specific way to handle this problem, but, if not, perhaps this will be useful to you and get you past your problem.

Comment: Thanks, @stephen for answering it though it didn't receive many votes :).  Do you have any time measurement for it, say exec time for 1M edge connected to a vertex? I went ahead with the soft delete approach to the vertex so the consumer can ignore during consumption

Comment: i don't remember unfortunately. i seem to recall some situations being under an hour and some taking much longer, but i can't remember what circumstances drove it one way or another. it always fascinated me as to how fat a vertex could grow with edges. cassandra never seemed to have a problem being fed more and more edges, but as soon as it was time to get rid of that thing, it was going to take a bit of thought and effort.